# Extjs grid colspan and row span

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, extjs

I would like to know is there is any way merge two cells of extjs grid.

[image: I uploded the image. Pls look into this]

`Ext.getCmp('grdHeaderTemplate').getView().getCell(0,1).dom.colSpan=2`

Comment: This may help you. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289819-RowSpan-in-Grid-How-to-merge-two-cells-from-different-rows

Comment: Thank you. But It is not working for me..

Comment: I found a lead in GitHub..https://github.com/x531tanxl/extjs-merge-cell-grid/blob/master/MergeCellTable.js   Bt it is still confusing..and It is in chinese..

Comment: Maybe you could clarify with a picture or a Fiddle to explain this one better.  Do you want all of the same column cells to have the same column span, or just certain ones?  Is there a piece of data you can key off of to determine this, any logic you can share, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing any further details, I think you're asking for something like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o44).  Basically this keys off of certain dummy data in the renderer to illustrate the point.

- For Lisa, it spans `Email` and `Phone`.
- For Bart, it's a normal row with no spanning
- For Homer, it spans `Phone`, `Alt Phone`, and `Alt Name`

The CSS is pretty minimal, but it could produce some side effects with changing the table width to 100%, but that is absolutely crucial.

```
.adjust-columns .span-columns {
    width: auto !important;
}

.adjust-columns .x-grid-item {
    /* This is pretty key... the framework sets a width of 0 on the table rows,
     * so this could have some other side effects */
    width: 100% !important;
}

.adjust-columns .hide-column {
    display: none;
}
```

And in the JS, like I said, I determine which class/colspan to apply in the column renderer.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'This should span the email and phone columns',
        phone: 'test',
        altName: 'Daughter'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '222-111-1224',
        altName: 'Son'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: 'This should span the Phone, Alt Phone, and Alt Name columns',
        altName: 'Dad'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    cls: 'adjust-columns',
    columnLines: true,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            var name = record.get('name');
            if (name === 'Lisa') {
                metaData.tdCls = 'span-columns';
                metaData.tdAttr = 'colspan=2'
            }
            return value;
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
            var name = record.get('name');
            if (name === 'Lisa') {
                metaData.tdCls = 'hide-column'
                return;
            } else if (name === 'Homer') {
                metaData.tdCls = 'span-columns';
                metaData.tdAttr = 'colspan=3';
            }
            return value;
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Alt Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
            var name = record.get('name');
            if (name === 'Homer') {
                metaData.tdCls = 'hide-column'
                return;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Alt Name',
        dataIndex: 'altName',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view) {
            var name = record.get('name');
            if (name === 'Homer') {
                metaData.tdCls = 'hide-column'
                return;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 600,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```